# How to deal with visually overlapping clusters

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, overlapping-data

I have done hierarchal clustering (average) and silhouette method shows 6 as the best k. However visualising I see that most of the clusters are overlapping. Any way to deal with the overlapping clusters? Does overlapping clusters show the problem with clustering?

Some stats: $average.between
0.8199681

$average.within
0.5613382

$n.between
18215

$n.within
5438

$max.diameter
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKAgk.png) 1

$min.separation
0.1666667

$within.cluster.ss
37.59716

$clus.avg.silwidths
(1)0.2679033  (2)0.2181911 (3)0.1480349 (4)0.1988496 (5)0.3415294 (6)0.2011643

$avg.silwidth
0.2187254

[image]
[image]

````
hopkins(Cluster, n=nrow(Cluster)-1) ## Seems to be clusterable as the value is 0.36 
## Also checked VAT
library(factoextra)
fviz_dist(dist.mat, show_labels = FALSE, order = TRUE)+ labs(title = "SR")
##Dist mat
library(vegan)
dist.mat<-vegdist(Cluster, method="jaccard", binary = TRUE)
##Cluster
Cl.hclust <- hclust(dist.mat, method="average")
Cl.cuts <- cutree(Cl.hclust, k=6)
# Statistics for clustering
library(fpc)
hc_stats <- cluster.stats(dist.mat,  Cl.cuts) # indices
hc_stats
##Visualize 
fviz_cluster(list(data = Clusttr2, cluster = Cl.cuts), geom="point") + ggtitle("Agglomerative clustering (average)")   ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the overlap is a visual artifact of reducing a high-dimensional space to a 2D space. I guess you used some PCA or multidimensional scaling technique to produce your plot? If I interpret your figure correctly, your "Dim1" captures only 15.9% of the variation so I would say that two dimensions are not very good at representing the whole dataset.

After cutting a tree produced by hierarchical clustering, a data point should belong to only one cluster. Perhaps you should be concerned about whether 6 clusters are not too many, but that depends on what you want to do with the clusters and how much separation you can reasonably expect.

Comment: thanks for the reply and help! I have not used PCA or multi-dimensional scaling techniques. Also I have assigned some of my clusters to other clusters to increase the value of average sil.width since it was negative for some clusters. Number of clusters was decided based on the result of Silhouette analysis. Would you suggest any other techniques for finding optimal k? My data is binary so I could not use gap or elbow...

Comment: You say: "*I have not used PCA or multi-dimensional scaling techniques*" so what is the plot you are showing and what is your input data? Showing some code would help. I don't have any particular suggestion about finding optimal k but if clustering results are not very neat it may be because there are no clusters in the first place.

Comment: I have updated my entry adding codes and other validation analysis I have run

Comment: I assume your "Cluster plot" comes from [fviz_cluster](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.7/topics/fviz_cluster) which in fact uses PCA when the number of dimensions is greater than 2 (which is probably your case even if you don't say it explicitly).

Comment: I did not know fviz_cluster used PCA. Does it mean that the clusters are good, but need to use a normal dendrogram to visualise the clusters rather than fviz_cluster?

Comment: Definitely, if you haven't done so already, plotting the dendrogram is the first thing I would do to assess whether 6 clusters is about right.